# Space issue when starting Weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic

we are trying to start our application server(Weblogic) but the below error comes up and we are unable to start it.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Can you please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 different errors resulting from their individual configurations.

**For this warning:**

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=512M; sup port was removed in 8.0

The `MaxPermSize` configuration was a Hotspot specific setting to specify the maximum perm-gen space for storing class files. You should either check your **Server -> Server start -> Arguments** if there is a `-XX:MaxPermSize` included that can be removed or you could check your startup scripts if specified there.

See [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) for details.

**For this error:**

> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

This results from heap allocation not enough. You need to add a `-Xmx512m` or an appropriate higher value.